# Find the least greater element on the right

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve an algorithm wherein I have to find the least greater element on the right of an array                    [reference](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-every-element-with-the-least-greater-element-on-its-right/)

For an instance in the below array 
Input: [8, 58, 71, 18, 31, 32, 63, 92, 
         43, 3, 91, 93, 25, 80, 28]

The least greater element on the right for the first element 8 is 18, for the second element 58 is 63 & so on. I need help with the logic to solve the algorithm. I intend to first solve with with brute force with a complexity of O(n^2).

The code I've written till now is below

```
public class Tmp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = { 8, 58, 71, 18, 31, 32, 63, 92, 43, 3, 91, 93, 25, 80, 28 };
    int[] tmpArr = new int[arr.length];
    int pos = 0;
    int k=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) { 
        //int next = arr[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if ((arr[j] > arr[i])) {
             tmpArr[k]=arr[j]; // take all the values to the right of the element which are greater than it
             k++;
            }
        }
```

I've created the second array tmpArr to take all the values on the right of an element which are greater than an it. Probably sort that array then & take the first value. But that logic doesn't seem ok to me.

Another solution can be

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) { 
    int leastGreater = ? //Don't know what to initialize with
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if ((arr[j] > arr[i])) {
                   if(arr[j]<leastGreater){
                 leastGreater = arr[j];
                  }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone help with a simpler solution?

Comment: (Initialise "current minimum variables" with (`Integer.`)[`MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#field.summary)) The problem linked reads `Given an array of integers, replace every element with the least greater element [to] its right`: please state whether you want to _find_ or _replace_.

Comment: Once I find I can easily replace, so the prb was finding. Now it's fixed once I initialized the leastGreatest variable with Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Please state in no uncertain terms, in the question, whether you want to _find_ or _replace_: for _replace_, I'd suggest `a simpler solution`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve it `O(n log n)` you may use `TreeSet` and go from right to left.

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
for (int i = ar.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    set.higher(ar[i]); // what you need, may be null
    set.add(ar[i]);
}
```

Comment: (Sort of mentioned in the GeeksforGeeks article linked in the question. (declare as [NavigableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#higher-E-))

Answer (score 2):

The second snippet is almost ok:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // (1)
    int leastGreater = -1; // (2)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if ((arr[j] > arr[i])) {
            if(leastGreater == -1 || arr[j]<leastGreater){ // (3)
                leastGreater = arr[j];
            }
        }
    }
    arr[i] = leastGrater; // (4)
}
```

1. We need to set the last element of the array as well, let the loop run over the whole array
2. If nothing is found the value should be -1, so initialize to that
3. need to replace also if nothing found yet
4. set the new value into the array

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
int a[] = {8, 58, 71, 18, 31, 32, 63, 92, 43, 3, 91, 93, 25, 80, 28};
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        int diff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int leastGreater = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
            if(a[j] - a[i] > 0 && diff > a[j] - a[i]){
                diff = a[j] - a[i];
                leastGreater = a[j];
            }
        }
        if (leastGreater == Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            System.out.println("Not Found for index " + i);
        }else {
            System.out.println(leastGreater + " found for index " + i);
        }
    }
```

It checks for difference to the right of current element which should be > 0 i.e right element should be greater than the current one.

Comment: int leastGreater = Integer.MAX_VALUE did the job

Answer (score 2):

use binary search and two-pointer technique. first sort the array, this function returns the index of least greater in `O(log n)` if exist otherwise returns -1

```
int LeasterGreater(int[] a, int value, int left, int right) {
    int low = left;
    int high = right;
    while (low != high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (a[mid] <= value) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid;
        }
    }
    if (low == right) {
        return -1;
    }
    return low;
}
```

example 1:

```
int[] arr = {8, 58, 71, 18, 31, 32, 63, 92, 43, 3, 91, 93, 25, 80, 28};
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int leastGreaterIndex = LeasterGreater(arr, 58, 0, arr.length);
    if (leastGreaterIndex >= 0) {
        System.out.println(arr[leastGreaterIndex]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("doesn't exist!");
    }
```

output:

> 63

example 2:

```
int[] arr = {8, 58, 71, 18, 31, 32, 63, 92, 43, 3, 91, 93, 25, 80, 28};
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int leastGreaterIndex = LeasterGreater(arr, 93, 0, arr.length);
    if (leastGreaterIndex >= 0) {
        System.out.println(arr[leastGreaterIndex]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("doesn't exist!");
    }
```

> doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0):

Can use a temp variable of location of the current/ smallest value greater than the target and one loop. Boolean is optional, more clear. Can  also use the temp var initialized to -1 & use as a flag in place of the boolean. 
Using one loop is faster for a bigger array and many calls. [Full source](https://github.com/tgkprog/academic/blob/master/src/main/java/arr/LeastGreater.java%20least%20greater)

```
        int[] arr = { 8, 58, 71, 18, 31, 32, 63, 92, 43, 3, 91, 93, 25, 80, 28 };
        // Test cases
        ap.findLeasterGreater(arr, 0);
        ap.findLeasterGreater(arr, 1);
        ap.findLeasterGreater(arr, 11);
        ap.findLeasterGreater(arr, 6);
        // without boolean
        ap.findLeasterGreater2(arr, 0);
        ap.findLeasterGreater2(arr, 1);
        ap.findLeasterGreater2(arr, 11);
        ap.findLeasterGreater2(arr, 6);

    /*
     * One loop L-R, check if first greater val encountered. Ini currGreater, when a new value that > orig but < currGreater, use that as
     * the currGreater Using the location of curr greater so can return that. More useful.
     */
    int findLeasterGreater(int[] arr, int loc) {
        int nextGreaterLoc = -1;
        boolean first = true;
        for (int i = loc + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (first && arr[loc] < arr[i]) {
                first = false;
                nextGreaterLoc = i;
            } else if (arr[loc] < arr[i] && arr[nextGreaterLoc] > arr[i]) {
                nextGreaterLoc = i;
            }
        }
        if (nextGreaterLoc == -1) {
            System.out.println("Not found a value bigger than " + arr[loc] + " (after location " + loc + ")");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found a value bigger :" + arr[nextGreaterLoc] + " at location " + nextGreaterLoc + " bigger than "
                    + arr[loc] + " (after location " + loc + ")");
        }
        return nextGreaterLoc;
    }

    /*
     * with 1 less local var - no boolean
     */
    int findLeasterGreater2(int[] arr, int loc) {
        int nextGreaterLoc = -1;
        for (int i = loc + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (nextGreaterLoc == -1 && arr[loc] < arr[i]) {
                nextGreaterLoc = i;
            } else if (nextGreaterLoc > -1 && arr[loc] < arr[i] && arr[nextGreaterLoc] > arr[i]) {
                nextGreaterLoc = i;
            }
        }
        if (nextGreaterLoc == -1) {
            System.out.println("Not found a value bigger than " + arr[loc] + " (after location " + loc + ")");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found a value bigger :" + arr[nextGreaterLoc] + " at location " + nextGreaterLoc + " bigger than "
                    + arr[loc] + " (after location " + loc + ")");
        }
        return nextGreaterLoc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy solvable in O(n), just have to look if the number you are currently expecting is between the current solution and the number corresponding to the input, then you can update the solution:

```
public static int getNextIntToTheRight(int[] arr, int index) {
  int ret = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // initialize
  for (int i = index + 1; i < arr.length; i++) // for all items to the right of index
    if (arr[i] < ret && arr[i] > arr[index]) // if the inspected item is better
      ret = arr[i]; // update on the fly
  return ret; // this is now the solution, if there is any, otherwise Integer.MAX_VALUE
}
```

Comment: this code gives each query in O(n), if you want to calculate for each index runs in O(n^2)

Comment: @mojtaba357 yes you're right, I concluded from *"Probably sort that array then & take the first value."* that he only wants to get one value and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class code44 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr = {1,9,7,56,36,91,42};
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int min = -1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[i]) {
                if (min == -1) {
                    min = arr[j];
                } else {
                    min = min > arr[j] ? arr[j] : min;
                }
            }
        }
        arr[i] = min;
    }
    for(int i =0; i < 7; i++)
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
    }
}
```

(or)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class code4{
    public static int MAX = 10000;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = {1, 9, 7, 56, 36, 91, 42};

        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            int min = MAX;

            for(int j = i + 1; j < 7; j++){
                if(array[j] >= array[i] && min > array[j]){
                    min = array[j];
                }
            }
            array[i] = min != MAX ? min : -1;
        }

        printArray(array, 7);
        sc.close();
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] array, int n){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

input : 1, 9, 7, 56, 36, 91, 42
output : 7, 36, 36, 91, 42, -1, -1

Answer (score -1):

what if the array is cirular form

Given a circular integer array nums .return the next greater number for every element in nums.

```
`Input=[9,1,2,4,3,5,8]

 Output=[-1,2,3,5,4,8,9]

9->-1 
1->2
2->3
4->5
3->4
5->8
8-9
```

Comment: the answer section is for ... answers, exclusively:)